# VBA Assigning Array to Range and Writing to Sheet returning all zeros

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to assign an array to a range of values in an Excel sheet.
When I do though, even though using debug the array is not all zeros, it returns all zeros.
The weird thing is for the *dat1* variable it does write to the cells correctly. Though that along with *dat2* is an array of strings.
Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Comparor()
Dim dat1() As Variant
Dim dat2() As Variant

dat1() = Sheets("Data1").Range("E1:E10").Value2
dat2() = Sheets("Data2").Range("E1:E10").Value2

Dim iTemp As Integer
iTemp = CInt(UBound(dat1))
Dim NumMatches() As Integer
ReDim NumMatches(iTemp)


Dim iNum As Integer


Dim iCompareInner As Integer 'dat 2 cycler
Dim iCompareOuter As Integer 'dat 1 cycler

For iCompareOuter = 1 To UBound(dat1)
    For iCompareInner = 1 To UBound(dat2)
        If (dat1(iCompareOuter, 1) = dat2(iCompareInner, 1)) Then
            NumMatches(iCompareOuter) = NumMatches(iCompareOuter) + 1
        End If
    Next iCompareInner
Next iCompareOuter

Dim test22(10, 1) As Integer
For iNum = 1 To UBound(NumMatches)
    'Debug.Print NumMatches(iNum)
    test22(iNum, 1) = NumMatches(iNum)
    Debug.Print test22(iNum, 1)
Next iNum

Sheets("Info").Range("E1:E10").Value2 = dat1
Sheets("Info").Range("F1:F10").Value2 = test22
Sheets("Info").Range("G1:G10").Value2 = NumMatches

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You wrongly declared `Dim test22(10, 1) As Integer`. This is a 2D array but it has **two columns**. It is a little more complex to explain, so I will post an answer, only to exemplify how such a situation produces, or have to be handled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Count Matches (Dictionary, CountIf, Array (Double-Loop))

- All three solutions do the same thing.
- Using them with some serious data, e.g. 1K uniques on 100K values (means e.g. 100M iterations in the array version) will reveal the efficiency of each code.
- But this is more about 2D one-based (one-column) arrays commonly used with (one-column) ranges.
- The code is basic i.e. no blanks or error values are expected and each range has at least 2 cells
  (i.e. `Data = rg.Value` with one cell doesn't work).

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub ComparorDictionary()
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Read values (duplicates)
    Dim vws As Worksheet: Set vws = wb.Worksheets("Data2")
    Dim vData() As Variant: vData = vws.Range("E1:E10").Value
    Dim vrCount As Long: vrCount = UBound(vData, 1)
    
    ' Count matches using a dictionary.
    
    Dim vDict As Object: Set vDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    vDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim vr As Long
    
    For vr = 1 To vrCount
        vDict(vData(vr, 1)) = vDict(vData(vr, 1)) + 1
    Next vr
    
    Erase vData ' values data is counted in the dictionary
    
    ' Read uniques (no duplicates).
    Dim uws As Worksheet: Set uws = wb.Worksheets("Data1")
    Dim uData() As Variant: uData = uws.Range("E1:E10").Value
    Dim urCount As Long: urCount = UBound(uData, 1)
    
    ' Write count.
    
    Dim uMatches() As Long: ReDim uMatches(1 To urCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim ur As Long
    
    For ur = 1 To urCount
        If vDict.Exists(uData(ur, 1)) Then
            uMatches(ur, 1) = vDict(uData(ur, 1))
        End If
    Next ur
    
    Set vDict = Nothing ' data is in the unique arrays
    
    ' Write result.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Info")
    
    dws.Range("E1").Resize(urCount).Value = uData
    dws.Range("F1").Resize(urCount).Value = uMatches
    
End Sub


Sub ComparorCountIf()
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference values (duplicates). No array is needed.
    Dim vws As Worksheet: Set vws = wb.Worksheets("Data2")
    Dim vrg As Range: Set vrg = vws.Range("E1:E10")
    
    ' Read uniques (no duplicates).
    Dim uws As Worksheet: Set uws = wb.Worksheets("Data1")
    Dim uData() As Variant: uData = uws.Range("E1:E10").Value
    Dim urCount As Long: urCount = UBound(uData, 1)
    
    ' Count matches and write the count.
    
    Dim uMatches() As Long: ReDim uMatches(1 To urCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim ur As Long
    
    For ur = 1 To urCount
        uMatches(ur, 1) = Application.CountIf(vrg, uData(ur, 1))
    Next ur
    
    ' Write result.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Info")
    
    dws.Range("E1").Resize(urCount).Value = uData
    dws.Range("F1").Resize(urCount).Value = uMatches
    
End Sub


Sub ComparorArray()
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Read values (duplicates).
    Dim vws As Worksheet: Set vws = wb.Worksheets("Data2")
    Dim vData() As Variant: vData = vws.Range("E1:E10").Value
    Dim vrCount As Long: vrCount = UBound(vData, 1)
    
    ' Read uniques (no duplicates).
    Dim uws As Worksheet: Set uws = wb.Worksheets("Data1")
    Dim uData() As Variant: uData = uws.Range("E1:E10").Value
    Dim urCount As Long: urCount = UBound(uData, 1)
    
    ' Count matches and write the count.
    
    Dim uMatches() As Long: ReDim uMatches(1 To urCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim vr As Long
    Dim ur As Long
    
    For ur = 1 To urCount
        For vr = 1 To vrCount
            If uData(ur, 1) = vData(vr, 1) Then
                uMatches(ur, 1) = uMatches(ur, 1) + 1
            End If
        Next vr
    Next ur
    
    Erase vData ' data is in the unique arrays
    
    ' Write result.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Info")
    
    dws.Range("E1").Resize(urCount).Value = uData
    dws.Range("F1").Resize(urCount).Value = uMatches
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The third solution is perfect for my needs. Ultimate goal will do more than just count matches which is why I was using double arrays to know the location of the match. Of course I'm sure match or dictionary could be made to work as well.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, one of your declarations is wrong and because of that, the unexpected result. Please, try understanding the next (didactic) code, to clarify the issue:

```
Sub testArray1D2D()
   Dim arr1D, arr2DStrange, arr2D, i As Long
   arr1D = Split("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j", ",")
   ReDim arr2DStrange(10, 1): ReDim arr2D(1 To 10, 1 To 1)
   For i = 0 To UBound(arr1D)
        arr2DStrange(i, 1) = arr1D(i)
        arr2D(i + 1, 1) = arr1D(i)
   Next i
   Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr2DStrange), 1).value = arr2DStrange 'it returns nothing
   Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arr2DStrange), 2).value = arr2DStrange 'it returns what you need in the second column (D:D)
   Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arr2D), 1).value = arr2D 'it returns correctly (what you need)
   Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arr1D) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(arr1D) 'also correct (a 1D array does not have any column! and it must be transposed. Otherwise, it repeats its first element value)
End Sub
```

When use declaration `Dim test22(10, 1) As Integer` it creates a 2D array but it has **two columns**. It is the equivalent of `Dim test22(0 to 10, 0 to 1) As Integer`. When you fill **only the second column (1) and try returning the first one (0), this column, is empty**.

The correct declaration for obtaining a 2D array with 10 rows and 1 column should be `Dim test22(1 to 10, 1 to 1) As Integer`.

Then, `iTemp = CInt(UBound(dat1))` declares a 1D array of **11 elements** (from 0, inclusive, to 10). And you never loaded its first element, starting iteration **with 1**. That's why the line `Sheets("Info").Range("G1:G10").Value2 = NumMatches` returned **the first empty element** 10 times... If your code would fill correctly the first element and if it was a matching one, your code will return 10 rows of 1 value.

`NumMatches(iCompareOuter) = NumMatches(iCompareOuter) + 1` is the equivalent of `NumMatches(iCompareOuter) = 1`. `NumMatches(iCompareOuter)` is always empty in that moment...

And it is good to cultivate the habit to avoid declarations `As Integer` in such a case. Working with Excel rows, the value of an Integer must be exceeded. Try using `As Long`. VBA is so designed to make the memory working in the same way, without any supplementary stress.

A more compact way to accomplish what you need will be the next approach:

```
Sub Comparor()
 Dim dat1(), dat2(), NumMatches(), mtch, i As Long

 dat1() = Sheets("Data1").Range("E1:E10").Value2
 dat2() = Sheets("Data2").Range("E1:E10").Value2
 ReDim NumMatches(1 To UBound(dat1), 1 To 1)

 For i = 1 To UBound(dat1)
    mtch = Application.match(dat1(i, 1), dat2, 0)
    If IsNumeric(mtch) Then NumMatches(i, 1) = "OK"
 Next i
 Sheets("Info").Range("G1:G10").Value2 = NumMatches
End Sub
```

Not tested, but it should work. Except the case of a typo, when an error will be raised and sending some feedback I will rapidly correct...

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. The explanations really helped me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

This for example

`Dim test22(10, 1) As Integer`

in the absence of `Option Base 1` is the same as

`Dim test22(0 to 10, 0 to 1) As Integer`

I'd use

`Dim test22(1 to 10, 1 to 1) As Integer`

if you want to match the arrays you read from the worksheet. Otherwise, dropping those arrays to a range only gives you the first "column" (which are all zeros since you never assigned anything there...)

Comment: I am new to VBA coding and should have checked when arrays start. Appreciate the answer.